# Scala map with keys of same type but with irregular  types for values and subtypes of values themselves being irregular

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scala map containing mix type values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584840/scala-map-containing-mix-type-values)

I have a situation where in a previous groovy program is constructing a structure like

```
mp = [k1: "string", k2: [d1: [1,2,3], d2: 1975], k3: 345, k4: ["one","two"]]
```

which amounts to:

```
[String: String, String: Map[String, Any], String: Int, String: List[String]]
```

The function returns mp to the calling function.

as you can see the values of mp map are irregular. I am rewriting the program in scala.

In scala I have to represent mp as Map[String,Any] but this results playing the dance with isInstanceOf and asInstanceOf in the test code that makes use of mp which results in a lot of scala boilerplate code. The main reason being Scala complains about List[String] cannot be cast to Any for example.

Is there a better solution in scala?

When looking more carefully, this question is different from my previous question. In this question, as you can see the value [d1: [1,2,3], d2: "string"] for key k2 is itself is irregular map.

I was proposing this solution:
Create another scala class like:

```
class MakeMap  {

// lot of code here
....

val k1: String  = // put here value found in logic above
val k2 : Map[String, Any]  // here is the issue, I am again forced to use Any
val k3 : List[String]  // put here value found in logic above

}
```

in test code:

```
val m1 = new MakeMap()
m1.k1  // very easy to access value, also gets rid of scala verbose syntax to access vale
      // in map like getOrElse
m1.k2  // this is the issue, it seesm I have to define yet another class
m1.k3 // again easy
```

Comment: What's the difference between this question and [that previous question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6584840/390581)? By the way, you mean *values* of different types; your keys seems to be all Strings.

Comment: Please post the error message, because you can convert a List[String] in any... If you want better solution in Scala, you have to stop trying to directly transpose solutions from Java or dynamic languages. If you detail the constraints you have on the keys and values, we can perhaps help you to find a proper Scala solution.

Comment: Sorry I did not realize this is similar to my previous question. I am asking this question when I am looking at a different context. Feel free to delete this question. My brain is partially damaged by scala :)

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Pellet, I realize now this question is indeed different from my previous question. See my edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are rewriting a code from Groovy to Scala, I suppose you are looking for performance and safety. So try to avoid using Maps to store everything because you may loose both. Try to define in advance the data structures you need, and use `case class` which could be seen as immutable structs.

For instance, an equivalent of the Groovy value:

```
[k1: "string", k2: [d1: [1,2,3], d2: 1975], k3: 345, k4: ["one","two"]]
```

Could be defined as:

```
case class Outer( k1: String, k2: Inner, k3: Int, k4: List[String] )
case class Inner( d1: List[Int], d2: Int )
```

Then you can create your object `mp` as:

```
val mp = Outer( "string", Inner( List(1,2,3), 1975 ), 345, List("one","two") )
```

And access members like:

val x = mp.k2.d2

Of course, give sensible names. Try first to constrain your types as much as possible, avoiding `Any`, `AnyRef` or `AnyVal`. It's often possible to do it.

Comment: case classes looks like nice solution but one thing I am trying to understand in my case I need to pass parameters to case class that are used to compute the other parameters and there is a of logic the case class has to use to compute the public class members. In your code it looks like the caller knows the values which he passes to case class and the case class simply return back these values when accessing them like val x = mp.k2.d2. In my case caller knows nothing about the values to be passed to case class when invoking it.

Comment: I think am now getting better understanding of case class. I am now making the return type to be case class for the function that actually does lot of business logic.

Comment: Yes. Try to build the case class in a factory method which computes all the field before returning it.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/6587#comment-27007) message on scala-user seems to address the use case you're interested in?