# Some constructor with asInstanceOf

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation, scala-option

When I was writing my [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918419/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-pass-around-dictionaries-containing-multiple-t/6924420#6924420) I also tried to solve the problem in more "functional" way, but stuck with the following problem:

```
scala> "1".asInstanceOf[Int]
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(Unknown Source)
        ...
```

but

```
scala> Some("1".asInstanceOf[Int])
res29: Some[Int] = Some(1)
```

and only

```
scala> res29.get
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(Unknown Source)
        ...
```

It looks like the Some's argument is lazy evaluated, but I can't find any clue in [the sources](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_1_final/src//library/scala/Option.scala#L249). The x parameter in the Some constructor is strict.

Why does Some together with asInstanceOf has such a strange behavior?

Comment: which scala version you are using? REPL in 2.9.0.1 throws exception immediately in both cases.

Comment: I reproduced it, but on a 2.8.1. Nice to know that it is fixed.

Comment: Scala 2.8.1, I actually use this version in production. And it will be nice to know what caused this behavior and in which cases it can appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor argument is not lazily evaluated. The moment you get the error is the moment when the REPL try to display the result, as an Int (`unboxToInt`). If you look further in the stack, you find `scala_repl_result`.

I believe the problem is that `asInstanceOf[Int]` does no check at all at runtime. I don't know whether it is according to spec (for value types) or a bug. The compiler is tricked into accepting that `"1"` is an `Int` (or boxed Int), pending a runtime check implied by asInstanceOf, but which will not happen.

As `Option`/`Some` are not specialized, at runtime there is only `Some[Object]`. So for the JVM, there is a call to a constructor new Some(Object o), which is accepted at code verification and at runtime. The `toString` (called by the REPL on the freshly built Some) is inside the generic code, where T is treated as `Object` too (or `AnyRef`), so it works, and `Some(1)` is displayed. On the other hand, every time there is an access to the value in the context where the compiler knows the type of the generic parameter, a cast is inserted in the code (+ unboxing in case of a value type). This is when it actually fails (here REPL does unboxing before displaying).

**Edit** This was in Scala 2.8.1. According to comment by @incrop above, this is now fixed.

Comment: Accepting this one because there is no more educated explanations. Hoping to finally know the exact reason of this bug though.